# A bound on the norm of the sum of two index-disjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Given two matrices, it is well known that $\parallel A+B \parallel _2 \leq  \parallel A \parallel _2+\parallel B \parallel_2$. Now, suppose that the nonzero indices are disjoint (i.e., $A$ is nonzero only where $B$ is zero and $B$ is nonzero only where $A$ is zero).

Can you see a sharper bound on the spectral norm of their sum?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If their supports are disjoint and your norm is the Frobenius norm, then you will have an equality.

---

In light of your edit, in this case the bound can be tight. For example consider $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &1\\1& 0\end{matrix}\right), \ \ B=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &0 \\0& 1\end{matrix}\right),$$such that $$A+B=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1 \\1& 1\end{matrix}\right).$$

In this case you can calculate that the equality is tight. You can generalize this construction to matrices of any dimension.

Comment: That's a pretty good observation, +1.

Comment: Sorry, I am specifically interested in the spectral norm. I edited.